# Finding all web elements using Ruby and Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, webdriver, element

I'm a Ruby and Selenium Webdriver noob...

Instead of grabbing one element at a time and placing it into a variable, I'd like to grab all of the web elements at one time, this includes buttons, fields, etc.

I've tried grabbing examples of find_elements from off the web but it's not working, so I'm doing something wrong.

So what do I need to do to grab all the elements of a web page and then how do I use a specific one?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You could create an xpath or css selector to fetch all the elements you want at once and store them in an array, but I don't think that is a very good practice. Simply fetch whichever element you need when you need it.

Comment: So, you want to simulate something like an `Object spy` of `QTP` type tool?

Comment: this is very bad practice, and there's not an easy way to do this. the typical way to automate, is to do it one element at a time.

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess I was doing it the right way.  I was trying to be a little lazy since there's about 30 fields in a form and I really did not want to learn all the objects one at a time.  But if that's the best way, let me get started.  Thanks again all.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my ignorance of Ruby having field decorators or some way to use PageFactory like in Java. There are several [great articles](https://solutionscafe.wordpress.com/category/webdriver/) and blog posts about using Page Object Model and PageFactory. It may not be exactly what you're looking for but maybe Ruby has something similar.

The gist of PageFactory is basically, creating a class for your page and add WebElement fields for your elements that have an id or name attribute. Use the same id/name value for your variable names. You can also use field decorators to pass a FindBy. Then you call PageFactory.init(factory, object) in the constructor and the PageFactory will find the elements or list of elements.

Let's see if I can give a QAD example that you can get the idea and then research using POM.

```
public abstract class PageBase implements WrapsDriver{

    protected String URL;
    protected String title;
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected ElementLocatorFactory factory;



    public PageBase(WebDriver driver, String pageTitle){
        this.driver = driver;
        this.title = pageTitle;
        this.factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 2);
    }

    abstract void open();
...

}

public class SomePage extends PageBase{
/*
*<div id="thin_client_viewer" style="position: relative">
*/
    public WebElement thin_client_viewer; 
    public WebElement primaryContentLink; //<a id="primaryContentLink" style="display:none" href=""></a>
    public WebElement loadingSpinner; //hidden <div id="loadingSpinner" style="display: none;">
    public WebElement top_toolbar; 
    .
    .
    .
```

you can declare lists and use custom decorators too:

```
   .
    .
    .

    /*
     * <div id="dijit_layout_LayoutContainer_0" class="dijitContainer dijitLayoutContainer       dijitAlignClient" >
     * 
     */
    @FindBy(css="div[id^=\"dijit_layout_LayoutContainer_\"")
    public List<WebElement> dijit_layout_LayoutContainer_;
    /*
     * <span id="TabbedNavigation_tab_0" class="tabLabel" dojoattachpoint="containerNode,focusNode" >
     * 

     */

    @FindAll(value = { @FindBy(className="tabLabel") })
    public List<WebElement> tableauTabbedNavigation_tab_;


...

public SomePage(WebDriver driver){

        super(driver, "Page Title");
        URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    }
@Override
public void open(){

    .
    .
    .
    PageFactory.initElements(super.factory, this);
    .
    .
    .
  }

    .
    .
    .
```

}

The class that instantiates or creates this page calls the open();

```
public class LoginPage extends PageBase{

       private WebElement somepage_link; 
       .
       .
       .
        public SomePage clickLinkToSomePage(){

            .
            .
            .

            driver.get(somepage_link.getAttribute("href"));
            somepage_link.click();
            SomePage page = new SomePage(super.getWrappedDriver());
            page.open();
            return page;
        }
    .
    .
    .

}
```